# Brake squeal when driving up a slope or turning right

Tags: brakes

There are many other brake squeal questions but the symptoms in the case of my car are different.

After driving for about 5 miles, I hear loud squealing noises from the wheel wells when I turn right or I drive up a sloping road. The speed of the car does not make a difference. The noise goes away when I apply the brakes.

I took the car to the dealer and they said the brake pads were not getting worn uniformly because I go very easy on the brakes - apparently there is 8 mm still left on a brake pad of 10 mm thickness after driving 30k miles. They said if the brakes are always applied lightly, then the pads do not wear uniformly because all parts of the pad do not make contact with the rotor causing this squeal and that the noise would go away after some time if I start braking normally.

Does the dealer's explanation make sense? Is it a known fact that always braking lightly will cause the brake pad to not wear away uniformly causing a squeal? If so why does it squeal only when turning right or driving up a slope?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that it is possible to brake using only part of a flat pad, unless there is corrosion on the rotors.

Comment: @HandyHowie some brake pads have a bit of a chamfer when they are new, like in the picture in [this answer](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/9568/675)

Comment: @Zaid  Yes, but I would be very surprised if that is what they are talking about though.

Comment: @HandyHowie I agree, using it as an explanation for squealing brakes is seems a bit... far-fetched

Answer (score 1):

Even if the break pads are not engaging the in same time, or are not worn out uniformly, will still not make a squeaking sound. So the explanation of your dealer makes no sense.

I had a similar problem - the rotor from the rear left was corroded and when the break pads were engaged the rotor used to vibrate, hence creating a squeaking sound.

I strongly suggest to consult a mechanic in this matter.

More info here: http://hubpages.com/autos/4-Common-Brake-Squeaks

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to apply liberal amounts of brake cleaner or even strip the calipers, clean up the moving parts (sliders, etc) with a stiff brush / emmery paper then apply a film of copper slip to the BACK (NOT FRICTION SIDE) of the brake pads and reassemble.

The other possibility is that the pads have been fitted without their anti-squeal shims (the thin metal plates that go behind the pads on some setups).

The final thing you could check is that the backplate (splash guard) isn't loose or out of shape and touching the disc at certain points.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very light on your brakes and use is not frequent then when you do allpy the brakes the initial effect will be to clean the light film of rust that has formed - with some getting embedded in the brake pad. Repeating the results in a oxide "glaze" on the disc surfaces. Also if associated with turning it likely that the calipers do not have enough float and with need cleaning at the next service.

Answer (score -1):

Put on new pads and clips but my brakes squeal only when I turns. Not when I brake. I found a youtube that probably provides than you need to clean and lube some of the non brake pad parts.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68zZbdFPTbA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/64529)